# Stuck with ObjC and MapKit CoreLocation

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I've been getting into mapkit and corelocation for ios. I'm just trying to display a map and zoom in on my current location for now. I can draw the map, with my location. I can get my current location. I just can't get the location data into the map method. I'm a bit of a noob, but thought I knew what I was doing up until this point! :) Any help is appreciated. My code is here, which sort of works but plonks me in the middle of the Atlantic at 0 long and 0 lat!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setPurpose:@"What use is a nav app if it doesn't know where you are?!?"];
[locationManager setDelegate:self ];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:10];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];
mapView.showsUserLocation = TRUE;
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;


MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
span.longitudeDelta=0.2;

CLLocationCoordinate2D location = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.span=span;
region.center=location;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView    regionThatFits:region];
[self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
      fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D here = newLocation.coordinate;
NSLog(@"%f  %f", here.latitude, here.longitude);

[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Comment: Are you using the Simulator or an actual device?

Comment: I've tried it on both. Exactly same results, only location on simulator is shown as Cupertino. location on iphone shows London. Not sure how to get my current location coords into the map.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's just me, but I don't understand the question entirely - your location is displayed on the map but you can't get the location into which map method? Where does it return (0, 0)?

Comment: Sorry it's late. The location that it zooms in to is where the equator crosses the meridian. i.e. 0 lat and 0 long. I want to zoom in on the current location (London). in viewDidLoad I've set a CLLocationCoodrdinate2D to get userLocation.coordinate from the mapView. but it's retunrning a null coord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map view `userLocation` will not usually be available right after setting `showsUserLocation` to YES.

Implement the map view's delegate methods `didUpdateUserLocation` and `didFailToLocateUserWithError`.  You'll need to set the map view's `delegate` property or they won't get called.  Change the map's region or center in the `didUpdateUserLocation` method--not in viewDidLoad.

Or, set the region in the CLLocationManager's `didUpdateToLocation` which you've implemented.  Does it get called?  Also implement its `didFailWithError` method and see if it gets called.

You only need to use either showsUserLocation or the CLLocationManager, not both, to get the current location if you're using MKMapView.  But to get the blue marble, you need to use showsUserLocation.

Also, why are you doing insertSubview twice on mapView?

Comment: Thanks. That did it. I changed the maps center in the didUpdateToLocation method and it works as expected. Also removed one of my insertSubviews. Many Thanks